# Is "Good-Till-Cancel" order good for 90 calendar days or 90 working days?

Tags: trading

Please tell me if Good Till Cancelled orders are good for 90 calendar days or 90 working days. Or, how are these 90 days counted.

[This definition](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/gtc.asp#:%7E:text=Good%20%27til%20canceled%20(GTC)%20describes%20a%20type%20of%20order,(active)%20to%2090%20days.) is vague,

> Good ’til canceled (GTC) describes a type of order that an investor
> may place to buy or sell a security that remains active until either
> the order is filled or the investor cancels it. Brokerages will
> typically limit the maximum time you can keep a GTC order open
> (active) to 90 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTC orders have a life span of 90 calendar days.

Answer (score 2):

It is in *calendar days*.
Note that at some providers, GTC means 60 days (example: https://investor.vanguard.com/stocks/trading), or even 'End-of-the-Month'.